# Why is there lifetime issue with Option::map's argument?

Tags: rust

I place a string into an `Option` and try to map over it, e.g. to trim the string:

```
fn main() {
    let s = "     i want to be trimmed    ".to_string();
    let s_opt = Some(s);

    let x = s_opt.map(|z| z.trim());
    //     let x = s_opt.map(|z| z.trim().to_string());

    println!("'{:?}'", x);
}
```

The compiler shows a lifetime error

```
error[E0597]: `z` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:5:27
  |
5 |     let x = s_opt.map(|z| z.trim());
  |                           ^      - `z` dropped here while still borrowed
  |                           |
  |                           borrowed value does not live long enough
...
9 | }
  | - borrowed value needs to live until here
```

This is clear, since `z` is only defined in the closure and the argument is passed by value.

Since the original variable `s` lives for the entire block, shouldn't the compiler be able to figure out that `z` is actually `s`?

The only way I can get this to work is by adding `to_string` (see the commented line), but then I am creating a new string object.

Another solution I found is to make `s_opt` a type of `Option<&String>` (see the second code block), but since functions can't return this kind of type this is not really an option.

```
fn main() {
    let s = "     i want to be trimmed    ".to_string();
    let s_opt = Some(&s);

    let x = s_opt.map(|z| z.trim());
    println!("'{:?}'", x);
}
```

Is there something I've overlooked or wouldn't it be better if the default implementation of `map` would be similar to this?

```
fn my_map<'r, F>(o: &'r Option<String>, f: F) -> Option<&'r str>
where
    F: Fn(&'r String) -> &'r str,
{
    match *o {
        None => None,
        Some(ref x) => Some(f(x)),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = "     i want to be trimmed    ".to_string();
    let s_opt = Some(s);

    let x = my_map(&s_opt, |x| x.trim());
    println!("'{:?}'", x);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `map` function consumes iterated values so they do not exist after the call to the given closure anymore. You cannot return references to them.

The best solution would be in-place trim on `String` directly. Sadly there is none in the standard library currently.

Your second solution is also possible with a small change. Instead of `&String` you take a `&str`:

```
fn main() {
    let s = "text".to_string();
    let s_opt = Some(s.as_str());
    let x = s_opt.map(|z| z.trim());
    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```

Comment: Thank you PEPP for your reply. I actually got the problem while using std::io. There the returned type is `IoResult<String>` (for example read_line). Thus the second solution cannot be used. As a consequence I have to use the `as_slice().trim().to_string()` solution or use the try! macro and wrap it in an extra function. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

As noted, `Option::map` *consumes* the original value to produce the output value. This is the most flexible and efficient implementation as you can convert an `Option<A>` to an `Option<B>` without needing to clone the original value.

The solution in this case is to convert your `Option<String>` (really a `&Option<String>`) into an `Option<&String>` using [`Option::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref). Once you have an `Option<&String>`, you can consume it without losing ownership of the original `Option<String>`:

```
fn main() {
    let s = Some("     i want to be trimmed    ".to_string());

    let x = s.as_ref().map(|z| z.trim());

    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```