# Borrowed value does not live long enough in Option::map

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Compiling the following snippet:

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let base = env::home_dir()
        .map(|p| p.join(".foo"))
        .map(|p| p.join("bar"))
        .map(|p| p.display())
        .expect("dir not loadable");
    println!("Name: {}", base)
}
```

I get the error:

```
error[E0597]: `p` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:7:18
   |
7  |         .map(|p| p.display())
   |                  ^         - `p` dropped here while still     borrowed
   |                  |
   |                  borrowed value does not live long enough
...
18 | }
   | - borrowed value needs to live until here
```

What is the reason of that mistake? What is the solution?

Comment: I believe your question is already answered by [Result of Option::map does not live long enough](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35249309/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this as already answered.

Comment: It is also answered by [Lifetime of Option::map's argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26056210/155423).

Comment: The duplicate's information [applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a8e0b0d861cc8e46fb0f006aaef175fa&version=stable&mode=debug).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Result of Option::map does not live long enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249309/result-of-optionmap-does-not-live-long-enough)