# How to convert the inner value in an Option?

Tags: rust, option-type, rust-2018

I have an `Option` that contains some JSON. If it is `Some`, the inner JSON must be converted, but if it is `None`, it must remain `None`.

This is how I have this implemented currently:

```
struct One;
struct Other;

impl One {
    pub fn convert(&self) -> Other {
        Other {}
    }
}

fn example(attr: Option<One>) -> Option<Other> {
    match attr {
        Some(attr) => Some(attr.convert()),
        None => None,
    }
}
```

I'm new to Rust and don't fully get the intricacies of when to use `match`, `if let` or when to use the `?` operator.

Is my implementation idiomatic Rust? It seems rather verbose to me, and looks like a pattern that will occur all over the place, so I can imagine this can be handled far more concise; is that so?

Comment: As the Shepmaster's answer points: use map but as an alternative you can replace the `match` part with this: `Some(attr?.convert())`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`Option::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map):

```rust
fn example_a(attr: Option<One>) -> Option<Other> {
    attr.map(|v| v.convert())
}
```

Since your function accepts a reference, you can also use [`Option::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) and then directly use the function inside of `map` instead of a closure:

```rust
fn example_b(attr: Option<One>) -> Option<Other> {
    attr.as_ref().map(One::convert)
}
```

See also:

- [Converting from Option<String> to Option<&str>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31233938/155423)
- [Lifetime of Option::map's argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26056210/155423)
- [How to implement some convenient methods (e.g., flat_map, flatten) on Option?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28566531/155423)
- [Use Option::map to Box::new a trait object does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48864045/155423)
- [How to convert Option<&T> to Option<T> in the most idiomatic way in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51338579/155423)
- [Is it possible to convert Option<Result<T, E>> to a Result<Option<T>, E> without using match?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43166393/155423)